# How to avoid full table scan query between dates

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

I am writing a stored proc to insert summarized values into task_activity_report table from task_history table.

Table

```
Task_history
----------------------------------------
Task_id                    Varchar2(32) PK
Event_dt                   Date
Event                      Varchar2(10)
......
......
......
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT task_id 
FROM   task_history 
WHERE  event = 'CLOSED' 
       AND event_dt BETWEEN 10 - nov - 13 AND 20 - nov - 13;
```

Between dates is doing full table scan, how to avoid full table scan query between dates??
select task_id from task_history where event_dt between 10-NOV-13 AND 20-NOV-13;

My table has 15millions+ records

Thanks for your help and time on this. Much appropriated.

CVSR Sarma

Comment: It basically SQL query. I am writing Oracle stored proc.

Comment: create non clustered index on EVENT include taskid,create non clustered index on event_dt .Also just use proper datetime parameter and don't use any cast/convert in even_dt

Comment: Possible Monthly Partition, helps sometimes

Comment: Please post the DDL for the relevvant columns in your table, the indexes, the explain plan of your query, the cardinality of your columns, the number of rows you expect to be returned by your query and the actual query, as this one is incorrect and will error. Without this information any help you get will, of necessity, be vague.

Comment: EVENT_DT DATE, TASK_ID VARCHAR2(32), EVENT VARCHAR2(10), and other columns... Which are not required...

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include extra information @sarma. But, there's quite a bit extra that I said would be needed to get a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create index on 'event_dt'-column.

**Updated**

I don't know your query plan and histograms, but may be index on 'event' field will be usefull too.

Comment: I have created index on all varchar fields.

Comment: if event_dt is varchar then this itself  a major problem

Comment: Did you create index on event-dt field ? Did you create index on ebent field ? Which type of SQL Server do you use ?  Can you show us your query plan ?  If you have index on fields in the WHERE clause you will get INDEX SEEK or INDEX SCAN instead of TABLE SCAN.

Comment: Well, the table is a like big book where you want to find some information.  And index it is like an index on the book (sorry, for my english). If you are searching information by event-dt and event fields the indexes on this fields will help you.  Any other indexes doesn't matters in this case.  Moreover any additional index makes inserts, deletes and updates more slowly.